# jar SSL connection in cygwin

Tags: ssl, command-line, jar, cygwin, truststore

I have a jar which calls an https endpoint. I'm using

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore
```

to point to the server certificate. Running the jar on Windows 8.1 in the command prompt works as expected, but if I start it in cygwin via mintty I get the following error when trying to access the https endpoint:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty;

Why does it work in the command propmt and how can I fix it for cygwin?